# Endung in "eine/eins oder zwei Katzen"

Tags: usage, grammatical-number

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   [Article for "a book or two"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9814/)

---

> Ich glaube, Paul hat (eine/eins) oder zwei Katzen.

Was ist hier richtig? Es scheint, als ob es *eine* sein müsste, aber "eine oder zwei Katzen" klingt irgendwie komisch, weil es nicht "eine Katzen" heißt, sondern "eine Katze".

Comment: Related: [Article for “a book or two”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9814/9551)

Comment: _Paul hat 1 oder 2 Katzen._ 

Comment: @Jan: Die Begründung für das Nicht-Dublette-Sein ist natürlich Unsinn und hätte sowieso besser ein Kommentar sein sollen; aber es ist trotzdem keine Dublette, weil die eine Frage deutsch und die andere englisch ist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"**Eins**" ist falsch, "**ein** oder zwei Katzen" oder "**eine** oder zwei Katzen" ist richtig. "Eins" wird nur beim Rechnen und Zählen benutzt, in Verbindung mit einem Substantiv wird die Form des unbestimmten Artikels verwendet. Vor *oder*, *bis*, *und* usw. kann "ein" auch ungebeugt bleiben. Einzelheiten z.B. bei [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Kardinal.html?MenuId=Word340).

Comment: Eins wird auch für sächliche Wörter benutzt. "Sie versuchte die 3 Kätzchen im nahen Bach zu ertränken. Eins konnte sich retten."

Comment: @user unknown: Das ist aber ein anderes Wort, nämlich das Indefinitpronomen _eines_ als Vertreter eines Substantivs, bei dem das _e_ entfallen kann. Deutlicher ist der Unterschied vielleicht bei _mein_ und _meiner_ zu sehen: _Ist das mein Buch? – Nein, mein(e)s._

Comment: Ich stimme zu, dass es ein anderes Wort ist, aber da 'eins' ja so oder so falsch wäre kann man schlecht sagen, welches der falschen 'eins' zu verwenden versucht wurde.

Answer (score 5):

Die korrekte Form ist zunächst

> eine (oder zwei) Katze(n).

Denn das Zählwort eins wird als Adjektiv dem Geschlecht (weiblich) des Hauptwortes (Katze) angepasst. Die Form **eins** an sich kann nur einzeln stehen, als Zählwort

> eins, zwei, drei

und als (sächliches) Substantivpronomen

> Wie viele Kinder hast Du? — Ein(e)s.
>
> Wessen Kind ist das? — Mein(e)s.

Die Formen mit und ohne »e« sind beide richtig. Es geht sogar noch weiter:

Es gibt (vermutlich aufgrund der häufigen Benutzung) eine Menge Ausnahmen und feststehende Redewendungen im Zusammenhang mit dem Wörtchen »ein(-e-s/r)«, die [der Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_Zahl) ausgiebig aufführt.

Die verstümmelte Form ist zweifellos in

> ein und derselben Straße, ein für alle Mal, ein und alles

nicht durch »eins« ersetzbar, ohne dass es holp(e)rig klingt. (Das mag in manchen Dialekten anders gesehen werden, die diese Vereinfachung im Laufe ihrer Entwicklung nicht mitgemacht haben.) Aber bei

> ein(e) oder zwei Katzen, ein(e) oder zwei Wochen

läuft das. Hingegen ist bei männlichen oder sächlichen Substantiven wie

> ein (oder zwei) Jahre, ein (oder zwei) Kinder

nur »ein« (wie »ein Jahr«) grammatikalisch richtig.

Answer (score 4):

*Eins* is falsch, *eine* nicht, aber ich würde *ein* sagen.

Entschuldige, dass ich das *ein* nicht begründen kann.

Answer (score 1):

Es muss *eine* Katze heißen, da man mit *"[...] eine **oder** zwei Katzen."* einmal den Fall hat, dass Paul entweder **eine** Katze hat, oder zwei. Das *n* bei Katzen stammt von der Möglichkeit, das Paul auch zwei Katzen haben könnte.