# Usage of "der ein oder andere"

Tags: usage, declension

I've seen this expression starting with {das eine, das ein, der ein, die eine, etc}. I can't wrap my head around this phrase, I understand that it means one or two, but why does the article and the ending of *ein* change? Does the article belong to *eine* or something else?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/endung-in-eine-eins-oder-zwei-katzen The top-voted answer answers your question, but it’s in German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article depends on the gender of the substantive it refers to as in all cases. `Ein/Eine`, in this case, is not necessarily that source, it refers to another substantive (that can be placed right after the expression or in another sentence) and it itself depends on that substantive's gender.

An example could be:

> Ich treffe zwei Personen.
>   Die eine Person ist älter als ich.

As Person is `femininum`, you use `die eine`.

A use of "das ein, der ein" should not be correct grammar as the definite article needs to have the same gender as the indefinite one. The word combination can still occur, for example in relative clauses, but that is not the same meaning or application.

Comment: "Wir sind heute bei der EXPOLINGUA und vielleicht erinnert sich der ein oder andere: Wir waren im letzten Jahr schon mal hier mit Manuel." 

This is the sentence I'm really interested in. In this case what is the noun phrase that der refers to ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Er flocht den ein oder anderen Witz in seine Rede ein._

Comment: Der ein oder andere wird "der ein" und "das ein" durchaus als richtig ansehen. Das ein oder andere Beispiel findet man dank Google.

Comment: Das gilt sogar, wenn die ein oder andere Frage dabei offen bleibt.

Comment: In this case it's part of an expression. I was lacking the information of the whole expression. In this case it's referring to the audience that sentence is adressed too. It translates to "maybe some of you remember".

Answer (score 2):

The confusion arises from using **ein** as a pronoun or article *vs.* using it as a **numeral**. Both are spelt the same but declension varies.

Hence [both expressions may occur](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_Zahl):

> der eine oder andere - der ein oder andere
>   in einer und derselben Straße - in ein und derselben Straße
>   Wir sind einer und derselben Meinung - Wir sind ein und derselben Meinung