# Role of "den" in the following sentence

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronoun

This phrase got me so confused. What is the role of "den" in the following sentence? Is it a relative pronoun? If yes, what is it referring to?

*Vielleicht ist es möglich, ***den*** einen oder anderen Trick der Geräuschemacher zu erraten.*

Comment: Related, but will probably not answer your question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27253/usage-of-der-ein-oder-andere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fix construction *der eine oder andere* (one or two). You are just seeing this construction in accusative, namely *den einen oder den anderen*.

Answer (score 5):

That *den* is the article belonging to the noun *Trick*.

> Vielleicht ist es möglich, **den** einen oder **(den)** anderen **Trick der Geräuschemacher** zu erraten.

Let's simplify:

> Vielleicht ist es möglich, **den Trick der Geräuschemacher** zu erraten.

So this noun phrase is the accusative object inside the infinitive clause. It's *what* can be guessed: the trick of the foley walkers.

Your question should be about that part I left out: *einen oder anderen*. The equivalent English phrase *one or the other* is odd in English, it's both indefinite and definite. In German it's definite. German often uses definite phrases when English uses indefinite phrases. You have to be aware of that.

Comment: Thank you so much :)